# VOLVER COLOR AL ESTADO ORIGINAL ONCLICK JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

Resulta que estoy intentando que el div de color rojo, cuando le doy click se vuelva negro, pero al momento de volver a darle click vuelva a su estado original, no logro conseguirlo.

**js:**

```
function cambiarFondo(){
    color=document.getElementById("di1");
    color.style.backgroundColor="black";
}
```

**html:**

```
<div class="div1" id="di1" onclick="cambiarFondo()" onmouseover="entrar()" onmouseout="volverEstado()"></div>
```

**css:**

```
.div1 {
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    background: red;
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: Bienvenido @TheLocotes a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y de paso ganes tu primera medalla, también es muy importante que leas [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad, favoreciendo tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas.

Answer (score 0):

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  let color = document.querySelector("#color");
  color.addEventListener("click", cambiarColor);

  function cambiarColor() {
    let colorActual = color.style.backgroundColor
    if (colorActual == "red")
      color.style.backgroundColor = "black";
    else
      color.style.backgroundColor = "red";
    console.log(colorActual)
  }


});
```

```css
#color {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div id="color" style="background-color:red"></div>
```

Lo mejor es que lo hagas con estilos en línea, porque con estilos externos es más complicado ya que no puedes acceder a ellos con `.style.backgroundColor` tendrías que acceder primero a la *hoja de estilos*.

Answer (score 0):

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  let color = document.querySelector("#color");
  color.addEventListener("click", cambiarColor);

  function cambiarColor() {
    let colorActual = color.style.backgroundColor
    if (colorActual == "red")
      color.style.backgroundColor = "black";
    else
      color.style.backgroundColor = "red";
    console.log(colorActual)
  }


});
```

```css
#color {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div id="color" style="background-color:red"></div>
```

Muchisimas gracias!! de antemano. La estuve probando, y de esa manera no sabia capturar los enventos.. 
Te hago una consulta, a la funcion que me diste, se le podria agregar , otra funcion con la condicion de que al cambiarse al color negro, esta misma no se ejecute.
Esta seria la otra :

function entrar(){
        color=document.getElementById("di1");
        color.style.backgroundColor="#F43131";
    }

Comment: esta es una respuesta o una pregunta?

Comment: No respondas con una pregunta, edita tu pregunta, aun así no entiendo lo que quieres decir, quieres que al pasar el ratón por encima cambie a otro color?

Answer (score 0):

Creo que lo más fácil sería utilizar una clase `.negro{background: black;}`. En el JavaScript puedes utilizar `div1.classList.toggle("negro")` para agregar o quitar la clase `.negro` al elemento `.div1`

```js
let div1 = document.querySelector(".div1");

div1.addEventListener("click",()=>{div1.classList.toggle("negro")})
```

```css
    .div1 {
     width: 500px;
     height: 500px;
     background: red;
     float: left;
    }
    .div1.negro{background: black;}
```

```html
<div class="div1" id="di1" ></div>
```